# Image gets cropped on only one place wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, image

The image I uploaded on wordpress had a dimension of 250x357 and gets uploaded good at [this page](http://www.planetzone.nl/winactie-grimsby/). But the same image is being cropped to 250x240 on [this page](http://www.planetzone.nl/). I don't know what to do, and I tried alot of things but the image just gets cropped.

Also the image on the homepage (second link) must be 300x250, just want the image to be resized to fit it without streching. So with white borders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must find articles loot. And find call to featured image function. Maybe it's use `wp_get_attachment_image()`. Than you need change `wp_get_attachment_image( $image ,'cb-360-240');` to `wp_get_attachment_image( $image ,'full');`.